# Update a TStringGrid from different threads in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi

Is it possible to update a TStringGrid using a thread for each column the table has?

I am doing some calculations inside each thread and I want to add them to a column, so far I've got something similar but with a strange error.

After one thread gets the result for the current row in its column, it calls this procedure.

```
procedure TAnimator.Iteration(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TMyClass.AddData(TEngine(Sender).Data, TEngine(Sender).ID, TEngine(Sender).IterationsCount);
end;
```

Sometimes I get a table with all data from the threads correctly added. But, I might as well get a table where its first values in some columns are not displayed correctly.

```
|| Col  1 || Col  2 || Col  3 || Col  4 ||
||    1   ||        ||        ||    4   ||
||    1   ||    2   ||        ||    4   ||
||    1   ||    2   ||    3   ||    4   ||
||    1   ||    2   ||    3   ||    4   ||
||    1   ||    2   ||    3   ||    4   ||
```

Comment: Difficult to answer the question without knowing what the types are. What exactly is a "Table". Obviously if it is a GUI control then updates have to be done from main thread yada yada yada.

Comment: A `TStringGrid` is not a table. It's a visual component, and as such is not thread safe. You cannot access VCL components from a thread without using Synchronize or Queue, which means all updates happen in the context of the main thread. There are dozens of questions here about threads and VCL components, as well as the large comment block that the IDE adds to the generated source when you use `File->New->Other->Delphi Files->Thread Object' from the IDE's main menu. It's also in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Defining_Thread_Objects) - see the code.

Answer (score 5):

A `TStringGrid` is a visual control. The threading rule for visual controls is that all access to visual controls must be made from the main GUI thread. You are breaking this rule and suffering the consequences.

Your solution is to abide by the rule. Use `TThread.Synchronize` or `TThread.Queue` to make sure that all code that accesses visual controls is executed on the main GUI thread.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem doing the calculations on separate threads. However you have to update the grid with your calculated results from the main thread.

There are 2 fairly simple approaches:

- Do all calculations for the entire column in a thread. Then handle the `OnTerminate` event to update all the cells in a desired column.
- Use `Synchronize()` from your thread to update a specific cell of your grid each time a new value is available.

This should get you started. If you're having trouble with specifics, there are existing questions covering [`OnTerminate`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D+onterminate) and [`Synchronize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi+synchronize). If you still get stuck, feel free to ask another question.